# Java Strings to Int

Tags: java, string

I'm just stuck with a problem (maybe Simple). But I can't figure out how to solve it, maybe someone of you can help me.

I receive as input an string with this format:

D0001001.tiff

And I need to return the next one (given that the next one is the received incremente by factor of one.

Input: D0001001.tiff
Output: D0001002.tiff

No zero can be missed. The method I have is this (without refactoring ;) )

```
private String getNextImageName(String last_image_name)
{
    // Splits the name from the start to the . (not inclusive)
    String next_name = last_image_name.substring(0, last_image_name.indexOf(".") - 1 );
    String next_extension = last_image_name.substring(last_image_name.indexOf(".") + 1, last_image_name.length() - 1 );

    String next_name_without_D = next_name.substring(1);
    int next_name_withoud_D_value = Integer.parseInt( next_name_without_D );

    // Increments to get the new name
    next_name_withoud_D_value++;

    String full_next_name = "D" + next_name_withoud_D_value + "." + next_extension;

    return full_next_name;
}
```

But the results are not as the expected:

Input: D0002001.tiff
Output: D201.tif

--

There are some constraints, for example, the number of 0 can't disappear because eventually the file can hace different number:

D0001001.tiff 
or
D9999999001.tiff

but the second one goes only through 999

D0001001.tiff 
to
D0001999.tiff

By this moment I'm so stuck that I can't even think...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If would use Regexp instead to make the code a bit cleaner:

```
private static final Pattern imgPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(\\d*)\\.(.*)");

public static String getNextImageName(String last) {
  // The pattern captures the numerical value and the extension
  Matcher matcher = imgPattern.matcher(last);
  if (!matcher.matches()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentExecption("Not image pattern: " + last);
  }

  String prefix = matcher.group(1);
  String num = matcher.group(2);
  int numVal = Integer.value(num);
  String ext = matcher.group(3);

  return String.format("%s%0" + num.length() + "d.%s",
                prefix, numVal + 1, ext);
}
```

A couple of comments:

1. Lookup Regexp specification to understand patterns and captures.  The given pattern basically "returns" the numberical value and the extension
2. `String.format()` can format numbers and inserts `0` as pad as well.  `String.format("%02d, 1)` returns `"01"` while `String.format(%02d, 200)` returns `"200"`.

Comment: Throwing an Error seems pretty intense for a bad input. Why not IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: Thanks msaeed. It works perfectly. I don't even understand the code. But this afteernoon I´ll start to study regex. As it seems is very powerfull.

Comment: Horrible code compared to the #1 answer by penpen.  Why do people jump to Regex for solutions like this?

Comment: @Bill_K, penpen solution is the last line in my answer, you still need to parse the number and extension.  Regexp is good for that

Answer (score 3):

String.format can do the trick for the padding part, for instance:

```
System.out.println(String.format("D%07d", 10));
```

gives

```
D0000010
```

Comment: The size of number is not fixed.  Good hint though

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("D([0-9]+)(\\..+)");

private String getNextImageName(String previous)
{
  Matcher m = p.matcher(previous);
  if (!m.matches())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name: " + previous);
  String number = m.group(2);
  String ext = m.group(2);
  String next = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(number) + 1);
  int pad = Math.max(number.length() - next.length(), 0);
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(1 + number.length() + ext.length());
  buf.append('D');
  while (pad-- > 0)
    buf.append('0');
  buf.append(next);
  buf.append(ext);
  return buf.toString():
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.*;
import static java.lang.Long.*;
import static java.lang.String.*;

...

String fileName = "D0009999.tiff";

String numericPortion = substringBetween(fileName, "D", ".tiff");
int minimumNumberOfDigits = numericPortion.length();
long numericValue = parseLong(numericPortion);

String nextFileName = format("D%0" + minimumNumberOfDigits + "ds.tiff", ++numericValue);
```

Comment: this is another elegant solution. And I understand it :D Cool SingleShot

Comment: Nice solution.  Solves this problem perfectly.  Not quite robust though.

Comment: Thanks msaeed. What do you mean by "not quite robust"? Lack of handling number format exceptions and such or something else? Thx.

Comment: This would fail if he got a 'jpeg' image or one that starts with `DMC` or any of the other common prefixes.  Works great for this limited use though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getNextImageName(String s) {
    int t = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1,8));
    return new Formatter().format("D%07d.tiff", (t + 1) % 2000).toString();
}
```

I wasn't sure if you were saying the numbers wrapped at 1999, if they don't, you should take out the `% 2000`.

Comment: The problem is that as I mention, the number of characters within the name is not fixed. But that class is very useful.